# Value of "Closure" when displaying property from object (after compiling to javascript)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am having problems where my Angular Dart application is behaving considerably different when running as javascript than running in dartium.  The simplest case I can boil it down to is:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<body test-case ng-cloak>
  {{ctrl.test.name}}
  {{ctrl.getObjName()}}

  <script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js"></script>
  <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//then my controller:
@NgController(
  selector: '[test-case]',
  publishAs: 'ctrl')
class TestCaseController {

    DummyObj test = new DummyObj('foo');    
    String getObjName() => test.name;
}

//and my DummyObj:
class DummyObj {
    String name;
    DummyObj(this.name);
}
```

When I run this in dartium, it works exactly as expected, and displays:

```
foo foo
```

But when I run it as javascript, though, I get the following:

```
Closure foo
```

Can anyone help determine what is going on here? Am I making some sort of mistake that only reveals itself when running in javascript?

Comment: I can't duplicate your results with firefox. What browser are you using and what is your pubspec.lock?

Comment: It happens in both firefox and chrome.

Pubspec.lock at http://pastebin.com/meYGBcVf

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. In my main.dart (which I didn't list above), I included the @MirrorsUsed annotation, but my DummyObj wasn't in the list of targets.

```dart
@MirrorsUsed(
targets: const ['test-case'],
   override: '*')
import 'dart:mirrors';
```

If I delete that entire block, it works.  Thanks for your help, Ozan!